# Bitbucket API NodeJS package Bad Request 400 error when creating a repository

Tags: node.js, api, http-status-code-400, bitbucket-api

When I try to create the repository by using the code below I'm always getting the Bad Request (400) error. Bitbucket authentication is working fine because I was able to get the list of workspaces.

```
bitbucket.repositories
.create({"repo_slug": "testrepo", "workspace": "development" })
.then(({ data, headers }) => {console.log(data)})
.catch((err, message) =>  {
  console.error(err)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by adding the `"is_private": true"` parameter in the body like in the code below. The reason for this error is that I was trying to create a public repository inside the private project.

Working code:

```
bitbucket.repositories
.create({"_body": {"is_private": true}, "repo_slug": "bitapi3", "workspace": "canopymesh" })
.then(({ data, headers }) => {console.log(data)})
.catch((err) =>  {
  console.error(err)
});
```